# Android - Are there serious performance issues with sending a localbroadcast every half second?

Tags: android, localbroadcastmanager

Are there serious performance issues with sending a localbroadcast every half second?

Comment: Depends on the platform, Performance wise not likely however storage could become an issue if backend de-allocation isn't considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since that is all in-process, it should not be too bad on its own. What you do when you receive the broadcast might be a problem, but the local broadcast itself should not be a problem.